# What does "IDC" stand for in inductor for boost converter?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

In Webench at TI.com it states "IDC" as a parameter for the inductors.
What does this stand for?

Saturation current? max current? ripple current? something else?

Comment: DC current. \$I_{DC}\$.

Comment: so that is same as "Current Rating (Amps)" when selecting inductor in digikey then i guess?

Comment: Yes. The Rated Current is specified as the current that causes the inductor's temperature to rise about 40 degrees (Celsius or Kelvin).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I<sub>DC</sub> is the rated DC current.  This is the current that causes the inductor's temperature to rise the specified amount, usually about 40 degrees (°C or K).

There is also saturation current I<sub>sat</sub> (for cored types), which is the current for which inductance decreases L by the specified amount, usually -10% to -40%.

Comment: @Tim Williams - you are welcome to add to this answer if you think it useful.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon What's the convention on making sweeping edits to posts, anyways? I certainly see few if any examples of it in practice. (Have a few mins to chat?)

Comment: @TimWilliams OP will not be making any changes themselves at present. Note their rep.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yeah I know in this case; I was curious about more generally

Comment: @TimWilliams  I sometimes make substantial additions where it seems "a good idea" AND I expect that the answer owner will be happy with them. Due care needed.  In normal situations its not common.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Fair. That's about what I expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147809/discussion-between-russell-mcmahon-and-tim-williams).

Answer (score -1):

The term IDC in the context of electronical engineering refers to [Insulation-displacement connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation-displacement_connector), connectors that pierce the wire insulation during mounting. Anyone using this widely well-known term for anything else is confused.

Not to be confused for I<sub>DC</sub> which naturally means direct current, as opposed to alternating current.